# yesod with stackage is failing to install due to dependency problems

Tags: haskell, dependencies, cabal, yesod, stackage

I tried to set up a yesod project as follows:

```
mkdir sample_blog
curl -o cabal.config www.stackage.org/nightly/cabal.config
cabal install alex happy yesod-bin
```

However, I got the following error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
next goal: Cabal (user goal)
rejecting: Cabal-1.18.1.4/installed-d6c... (global constraint requires
==1.18.1.3)
trying: Cabal-1.18.1.3/installed-476...
trying: yesod-bin-1.4.2 (user goal)
next goal: ghc (dependency of yesod-bin-1.4.2)
rejecting: ghc-7.8.3/installed-1d5... (conflict:
Cabal==1.18.1.3/installed-476..., ghc => Cabal==1.18.1.4/installed-d6c...)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.

Note: when using a sandbox, all packages are required to have consistent
dependencies. Try reinstalling/unregistering the offending packages or
recreating the sandbox.
```

I've install GHC and cabal-install using homebrew.
Versions:

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.3


$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.20.0.4
using version 1.20.0.3 of the Cabal library
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that homebrew has patched the standard GHC installation, as it's shipping with a different version of the Cabal library than the official GHC. I don't know why that is occurring. A quick workaround would be to remove the `Cabal` line from your `cabal.config`. Can you open up an issue against Stackage about this? I'd like to get to the bottom of why this is occurring.

Comment: To confirm, you want an issue against stockage, and not homebrew.

Comment: Yes, that issue was good, thanks. It would be nice to have someone from homebrew explain why they have a different version in use. Now that I think about it, it's theoretically possible that *all* Mac users have a different version of the Cabal library.

Comment: By the way, when I have installed yesod-bin into my sandbox, what do I do now. If I create a new project using ./cabal-sandbox/bin/yesod init, I get a new subdirectory without a cabal-sandbox in it. So, how do I create a new project in the current directory?

Comment: `yesod init --bare`. We *just* updated the quickstart guide for this use case: http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart.